# Spring and Hibernate : how to declare a join to composite key (using annotations)?

Tags: hibernate, join, annotations

I need to join the "last version" number of my Project to the table Project_version.
How do I declare it with annotations @JoinColumn, etc ?

My table "**Project**" :

```
* Project_id
  Title
  ...
  LastVersion_id
```

My table "**Project_version**" (primary key = **Project_id + Version_id**) :

```
* Project_id
* Version_id
  DateCreat
  ...
```

My bean "**Project**" : I need declare the attribute "**LastVersion_id**" to join Project_version :

```
@Id
private Integer Project_id;
private String Title
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="LastVersion_id")
                    // How to declare the join to (Project_id + Version_id) ?
private Project_version pv;
```

Comment: You're right, this has nothing to do with Spring. But Hibernate is more often used with Spring.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I finally found the answer :

```
@Id
private Integer Project_id;
private String Title;
// ...
@MapsId("Project_id")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="Project_id", referencedColumnName="Project_id"),
    @JoinColumn(name="LastVersion_id", referencedColumnName="Version_id")
})
private Project_version pv;
```

Note that `@MapsId` is absolutely required, otherwise you got the error "Repeated column in mapping for entity"