# one to one join on composite primary key in jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two tables. One is having primary key and another one is having composite key.

TableA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
public class TableA {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "myId")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "myName")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "myRegion")
    private String regionName;
}
```

Composite key for TableB:

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositePK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "myId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long myId;

    @Column(name = "secondaryId")
    private String secondaryId;

}
```

TableB:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB")
public class TableB {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CompositePK compositePK;

    @Column(name = "Data")
    private String regulationText;
}
```

Now I want to implement the query

```
select * from TableA tableA 
        inner join TableB tableB 
        on tableA.myId=tableB.myId
        where tableB.myId = 1;
```

I have tried the below snippet in TableB (one to one join).

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "TableA", inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "myId", referencedColumnName = "myId"))
    private TableA tableA;
```

But it says that Invalid column secondaryId. Figthing with this for a day. Unable to join a table with primary key from composite key. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify `TableB` to use "derived identity":

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB")
public class TableB {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CompositePK compositePK;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "myId", referencedColumnName = "myId")
    @MapsId("myId") // maps 'myId' attribute of embedded id CompositePK
    private TableA tableA;

    @Column(name = "Data")
    private String regulationText;
}
```

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the JPA 2.1 spec in section 2.4.1.

Comment: Thank you so much @Brian Vosburgh. I have tried the solution. It exactly matches my requirement.

Comment: Excellent! : ) If you have time, could you accept my answer? @user3016222

Answer (score 0):

In case of composite you need to access it with the composite key object like as below :

```
 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(name = "TableA", inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
 "compositePK.myId", referencedColumnName = "myId"))
 private TableA tableA;
```

Comment: I have tried this. It is throwing exception that "Invalid column secondaryId". Since TableB contains Composite key it is looking for secondary column. But TableA does not have composite key. It has only primary key "myId" @ishantg

Comment: I found one solution similar to your question . May be it could help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936640/spring-and-hibernate-how-to-declare-a-join-to-composite-key-using-annotations

Comment: The above solution is not working out. Still I am gettng the same exception "Invalid column secondaryId"

Comment: This is the working solution :  https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/identifier/composite/CompositeIdOneToOneTest.java